# Odd divisor summation

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, mathematics

> Given an integer, k, we define its odd divisor sum to be the sum of all k's odd divisors. For example, if k = 20, then the odd divisor sum would be 1 + 5 = 6. Similarly, if given an array of values, we can find the odd divisor sum of the array by summing the odd divisor sums for each element in the array.
>
> For example, if array `K = [3, 4, 20]`, the odd divisor sum of the array would be `oddDivisorSum(3) + oddDivisorSum(4) + oddDivisorSum(20) = (1 + 3) + (1) + (1 + 5) = 11`.

This code works, but it does not pass all the cases due to time. I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way to write this. I heard that memoization could work, but I am not sure show how to implement it.

```
numbers = [3,21,11,7]

def  count(numbers):
    total = 0
    for k in numbers:
        for i in range(1,k+1,2):
            if k % i == 0:
                total+=i
    return total
```

Comment: I am not sure why someone voted to close as off-topic (broken code). As far as I can see, the code works correctly. Being too slow/inefficient for a programming competition is a valid (and frequent) reason to ask for a code review.

Answer (score 11):

First I would suggest to separate the code into two functions: One which computes the sum of odd divisors of a single number, and another which adds the odd divisors of all numbers in a list. Also, use better function names, and add at least a simple doc comment:

```
def oddDivisorSum(n):
    """Return the sum of odd divisors of n."""
    # ... to do ...


def totalOddDivisorSum(numbers):
    """Return the sum of all odd divisors of all numbers."""
    return sum(oddDivisorSum(n) for n in numbers)
```

This makes the code more clear, better reusable, and makes it easier to add test cases.

To make the computation faster, two observations help:

1. If \$k\$  is a divisor of \$n\$, then \$\frac{n}{k}\$ is also a divisor of  \$n\$.

   This is what Oscar also said, and it allows to restrict the search for divisors to the interval  \$1\dots \sqrt n\$. The "problem" is that \$k\$ and \$\frac{n}{k}\$ can have different oddity.
2. If \$ k \$ is an odd divisor of an *even* number \$n\$ then \$k\$  is also an odd divisor of \$\frac{n}{2}\$.

Therefore, we can remove all even factors of \$n\$ first, and then find odd divisors in the reduced (odd) number. This makes the code *simpler* (because *all* divisors are odd) and *faster* for even numbers (a smaller \$n\$ means less trial divisions):

```
def oddDivisorSum(n):
    """Return the sum of odd divisors of n."""
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n //= 2
    sum = 0
    for k in range(1, int(n ** .5) + 1, 2):
        if n % k == 0:
            sum += k
            if n // k != k:
                sum += n // k
    return sum
```

Comment: it might be faster to compute gcd(n, 2^64) and divide n by that, not sure though

Comment: @OscarSmith, if you're talking about micro-optimising the `while n % 2 == 0: n //= 2`, the faster alternative would be `n //= -n & n`. But the chances that that loop is the bottleneck are extremely slim.

Comment: @OscarSmith: I haven't benchmarked it (and Peter is surely right). I *think* I have seen gcd implementations which remove common factors of two *first,* which would be the opposite of what you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help.  I'll try it out and benchmark it, see if it makes a difference. :)

Answer (score 6):

> I heard that memoization could work, but I am not sure show how to implement it.

In Python you just use [built-in support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def ...
```

However, it won't get you much benefit.

The real key to this problem is understanding the structure of the factors of a number. For example, `count([1610612736])` should return `4`. Why?

> It factors as 2<sup>29</sup> 3<sup>1</sup>.

In general, any positive non-zero<sup>1</sup> integer can be written as \$n = p_1{}^{a_1} \ldots p_k{}^{a_k}\$ where the \$p_i\$ are distinct primes in exactly one way (the fundamental theorem of arithmetic). Any factor of \$n\$ has the form \$d = p_1{}^{b_1} \ldots p_k{}^{b_k}\$ where \$b_i \le a_i\$ for each \$i\$. Odd factors are those which don't have \$2\$ in their factors.

So the first thing to do is to ditch the twos:

```
while k % 2 == 0:
    k //= 2
```

Then factor into primes with multiplicity and compute the [sum of divisors](https://oeis.org/A000203), which is a multiplicative function.

<sup>1</sup> I'm being explicit because in some cultures 0 is considered positive.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for quadratic speedup is to realize that for any n, all factors x will be `x<n**.5`, or n divided by a different factor. With this in mind, the following instantly gives quadratic speedup.

```
def count(numbers):
    total = 0
    for k in numbers:
        for i in range(1, int(k**.5)+1):
            if k % i == 0:
                if k % 2 == 1:
                    total += k
                if (k//i) % 2 == 1 and i*i != k:
                    total += (k//i)
    return total
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this would for example not find the odd divisor 13 of 26 (because the iteration stops at i=3). Also the square root might be counted twice as a divisor. – Did you run this with the sample data `K = [3, 4, 20]` from the question?

Comment: oops, you're right, edited

Comment: Still does not work, `count([3, 4, 10])` returns `1`.  – Btw, `range` *excludes* the upper bound.

Comment: this has been embarrassing

Comment: Now `count([6])` returns 3 instead of 4. – I don't want to sound rude, but I would suggest to run more test cases, comparing your output against the result of the original function from the question.